# Подстановка параметров в запрос без кавычек

Tags: c#

Как подставлять в запрос параметры без кавычек? Необходимо подставлять название таблицы и название поля, переменные подставляются в кавычках и происходит ошибка в запросе, например:

```
select * from 'users' where 'name' = 'username'
```

Нужно же:

```
 select * from users where name = 'username'
```

Код:

```
    public bool Exist(string value)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @table where @field = @value", this.mc))
        {
            myCommand.Prepare();
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", this.unique_field);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", this._db_table);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PavelNewSky при таком подходе нет защиты от SQL инъекций

Comment: Значения и так подставляются "без кавычек" - но только значения. Кавычки - это просто способ записи значений в коде SQL. Просто через параметры нельзя подставить часть выражения - т.е. нельзя подставить слово `SELECT`, `WHERE` или имя колонки.

Comment: есть ли смысл защищать от инъекции имя таблицы или имя поля, если они не вводятся пользователем? видимо, через параметры нельзя передать имя таблицы или колонки. не заметил, что кто-то меня опередил, тезка)

Comment: @PavelNewSky да, в данном примере согласен, как то не подумал. Но бывают же случаи когда надо подставить без кавычек, например запрос типа "Where In (1,2,3,4)". Как в таких случаях поступать? Есть какое то решение для этого?

Comment: @Razorik признаюсь, с mysql до таких тонкостей не доходил, но разве нельзя сделать вот так: WHERE id IN (@user_ids), где user_ids = "1,2,3,4"?

Comment: @PavelNewSky тогда оно будет подставлено таким образом: "where id in ('1,2,3,4')", нет?

Comment: @Razorik да, но скорее всего будет работать, ну или извращаться и делать (@a,@b,@c,@d). в том то и дело, что к каждой проблеме свой подход, я предпочитаю думать, что создатели подобных библиотек разумные люди и всё нормально реализовали, осталось только нам понять, как это использовать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве параметров можно передать только значения (`'username'`, `42`), но нельзя поменять сам текст запроса. Т.е. нельзя спустить в качестве параметров `SELECT`, `WHERE` или имя колонки.

Если вам нужно подставить имя колонки - собирайте команду по частям:

```
public bool Exist(string value)
{
    using (var myCommand = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {this._db_table} where {this.unique_field} = @value", this.mc))
    {
        myCommand.Prepare();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

только убедитесь, что `this._db_table` и `this.unique_field` определяются у вас в коде, а не приходят в качестве параметров от конечного пользователя - иначе получите SQL Injection.